# how to re size a image with php before showing it to the browser?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, resize, image-resizing

i have some images that have a certain size and i want to scale them down.

i don't want to save them to scaled, i want to re size them each time the image load in the browser

i've took a look as the `WideImage` library and `imagecopyresampled`

if i use `WideImage::load($_GET['img'])->resize(500, 300)->output('jpg', 90);` and i echo this out i get the source code from the image and not the actual image.

i also fount this method

```
public function resizeImage($originalImage,$toWidth,$toHeight)
    {

        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalImage);
        $xscale=$width/$toWidth;
        $yscale=$height/$toHeight;

        if ($yscale>$xscale){
            $new_width = round($width * (1/$yscale));
            $new_height = round($height * (1/$yscale));
        }
        else {
            $new_width = round($width * (1/$xscale));
            $new_height = round($height * (1/$xscale));
        }


        $imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        $imageTmp     = imagecreatefromjpeg ($originalImage);
        imagecopyresampled($imageResized, $imageTmp, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

        return $imageResized;
    }
```

and if i pass a image to it and echo the result i get `resource(192) of type (gd)` and not the image.

also im not sure what image path to pass to this methods, the `http://.....jpg` or `/var/www/images/....jpg`

can anyone shade some light on this? it looks like i don't really understand how this process works

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using SimpleImage, it's really easy. Look at: [Resizing images with PHP](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/). But that's not about your problem.

Your code: `return $imageResized;` returns only gd Object, not real image. You need to transform it and you can do 2 things:

1. Load image by script url (ex: `http://localhost/image_converter.php?img=my_img.jpg`)
2. Return image data as URI scheme (Using URI is not good practice, because you have to work with output buffering, etc... and HTML datas are enormous, because images are directly in it ... look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples)

(example using your method)

You need to set proper header with `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`. And you have to use function `imagejpeg ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality ]] )` for GD object

```
<?php
/* image_converter.php */
$image = new Image(); //Will use method in unknown class found by you
$output = $image->resizeImage($_GET['my_img'],50,50); //We have gd object in $output
//!! DO NOT USE GET WITHOUT SECURING IT!
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($output); //This displays image dataa converted in jpg
exit;
?>
```

Called: `<img src="http://localhost/image_converter.php?img=my_img.jpg" alt="" />`

Answer (score 2):

Pass the local file name to the method not the url

You need to set the http headers for the image to be interpreted as an image

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: @Patrioticcow You need to set the `src` of the image to the php file that returns only the image.

Comment: So your trying to output an image in an html page? If so thats what the `<img>` tag is for

Comment: @Patrioticcow, if it isn't clear, the image needs to be at its own URL, you can't embed it in the page.